# How can a doped piece of silicon (with different concentration) still be intrinsic?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics, electronics

I am trying to solve a question which says:

> A piece of silicon is doped with Nd = 1.8*10^(13) and Na= 3.8*10^(13) Prove it is intrinsic at 500k.

I don't know how is it possible for silicon to be intrinsic after doping.

[image: Here is the question]

Comment: Those are very low doping levels. With that hint, proceed onward.

Comment: Now that almost a week has passed, go look in your book for a plot of the intrinsic carrier concentration vs temperature. See what it is at 500K. Note that for silicon it is about 2E14, which is 10x higher than either the donors or acceptors. The intrinsic carriers have overwhelmed your doping levels, and the material is now intrinsic.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An un-doped intrinsic semiconductor often contains small amounts of impurities that can make it behave slightly n- or p-type. Doping with nearly equal low levels of donor and acceptor atoms is called compensation. A compensated semiconductor behaves more closely like an ideal intrinsic semiconductor.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Which isn’t actually the point of the exercise...

Comment: @JonCuster did you down vote this good answer? Seems unfair if so.

Comment: @boyfarrell - it isn’t a good answer. It misses the whole point.